# Given a tensor and a graph how does TF Serving know what to do with them

Tags: tensorflow-serving

Given a set of inputs how does Tensorflow Server know how to execute a graph with its input data? In particular given the set of permutations of graph plust data how does tensorflow serving know what to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow serving requires a **saved model**. Documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel). Part of the saving procedure is to declare the input interface for the predictor. Tensorflow offers different means to define this interface. However, most methods do not allow much processing of the input data at the serving side.

What do you mean with 'permutations of graph plus data'? For prediction you possibly don't have permutations of data. And permutations of models are either done inside a frame model or outside using several models.

Comment: What I am trying to say is what is the mechanism on the server side that executes session->run. For me the documentation is not clear. I think one needs to create a servable that is loaded by Tensorflow server but I am not sure.

Comment: For tensorflow models you configure a file folder where the serving server finds the versions of the model (saved models). The documentation for the tensorflow serving docker container sheds some light on this. https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker

Comment: What I don't understand is how Tensorflow serving knows what to do with the input data provided by the client. If the client provides say an image and the name of the model if wants to use how does the server side of the equation know how to process the graph's execution such as session->Run? Does Tensorflow Serving contain a set of generic parsers that given a model and relevant data knows how to form  a tensor of the correct shape for execution? Or does Tensorflow Serving have a mechanism that allows a developer to create a server side plugin to handle specific client requests?

Comment: When you save a model, you have to provide a small input function or data structure which receives the protobuf data and converts them into the format your model expects. A basic description can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic.